# laravel rest api method view выдает ошибку 404

Tags: php, база-данных, laravel

CountryController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Country;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\Country;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class CountryController extends Controller
{
    public function country()
    {
        return response()->json(Country::all(),  200);
    }

    public function countryById($id)
    {
        return DB::table('country_lang')->find($id);
    }
}
```

web.php

```
Route::get('country','\App\Http\Controllers\Country\CountryController@country');
Route::get('country/{id}', '\App\Http\Controllers\Country\CountryController@countryById');
```

Есть таблица 'country_lang'  там есть данные.
Хочу выводить их по идентификатору но не получается. Возвращает 404 Not Found http://127.0.0.1:8000/country/1
Вывод всех данных работает
В чем может быть проблема. Если это 404 то думал проблема в роуте но там вроде все ок.

Answer (score 0):

Вижу 2 возможных варианта:

1)Дополнительно приводить id в инт `find((int)$id)`

2)доставать данные не через find а через `select()->where()->get()`